# Navbar Menu toggle button does not come on extreme right when collapsed

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I have tried a lot but the navbar menu toggle button comes in middle when collapsed however it moves to extreme right when i expand it. How can it stay on extreme right even when it is collapsed.

'''html

[image: Logo]
                    
                    
                    
                       
                       
                         
                          
                           Menu
                           Menu
                           
                         
                       
                       
                       
                         
                            [HOME](/index.php)
                            
                            ABOUT COLLEGE

College Profile

Principals Message

Vision & Mission

Committee List

Core Values

Photo Gallery

DEPARTMENTS

Computer Applications

Business Administration

Commerce

Mass Communication

Arts & Humanities

Sciences

SOCI-->
                            FACILITIES

Auditorium

Library

Browsing Centre & WI-FI

Sports

Girls Common Room

Hostels

Facilitation Centre

Conference hall

Medical Aid

Canteen

STUDENTS CORNER

Career Counselling Cell

Scholarships

Women Development Cell

Code of Conduct

Bonafide Certificate

IQAC

Overview

AQARs

PUBLICATIONS

Newsletters

Magazines

College Prospectus

-->

CONTACT

```
        <!--
        =====================================================
            Theme Inner page Banner
        =====================================================
        -->
        <section class="inner-page-banner">
            <div class="opacity">
                <div class="container d-none d-lg-block">
                    <font color="#FFFFFF"><b>GOVERNMENT DEGREE COLLEGE ANANTNAG</b></font>
                    <ul>
                        <li>NAAC ACCREDITED GRADE B+</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>  
            </div> <!-- /.opacity -->
        </section> <!-- /.inner-page-banner -->
```

'''

[image: image 1][image: image 2]
i use bootstrap 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please share your css or do a `{margin-left: auto}` on the 'Menu'

Comment: '''.theme-main-menu .navbar-toggle {
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  color:#fff;
  
}
.theme-main-menu .navbar-toggle .fa {
  font-size: 18px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.theme-main-menu .navbar-nav {
  margin: 0;
}'''

Comment: thank you. now it is fine. made this change   <div class="navbar-header" style="margin-left:auto;">

Answer (score 0):

You can align the text right in many ways.

1. Use max-width: 100px; and set margin-left: auto;
2. text-align: right;
3. float: right;

Hope, it helps.